# Automatically generating a new column to an existing excel file?

Tags: excel, dynamic, vba

Suppose there is an existing ms excel file. There are some data inside, taking 5 columns. 
Here is what I want to do:

1. I want the excel file to automatically generate a new column, the 6th, when the file is opened, say double-clicked.
2. I want the 6th column do some summation based on the indexing/flag information int he 4th column, and the values from 5th column. For example: Suppose 4th column has binary entries (1 or 0). If the entry is 1, then pick the entry in the same row in 5th column, and do the summation for all this kind of values (values in 5th column with a 1 flag in 4th column)

Is there anyway I can realize these functions? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need a macro for this ? Can you not just use regular functions ?

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur: Whatever that works, as long as a new column is generated when the file is opened. Any suggestions?

Comment: That's exactly my question. Why do you need to "generate" a new column ? To me that means that it must be deleted on close. Can you just leave formulas there and let them update on open ?

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur: No offensive, but if your boss wants to see that column every time when the file is opened, are you going to ask him to do some programming/typing?

Comment: @Nick: if your boss wants to see it everytime, you leave it there, you don't recreate it everytime, do you? What are we missing?

Comment: @nutsch: I am trying to do the assignment, and I believe someone knows how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula for this would be some version of, but additional clarity on the request would help precise.

```
=if($d2=0,"",sumif($D:$D,1,$E:$E))
```

Comment: Where do I put this? Any chance you can elaborate it?

Comment: You'd put it in cell F2, then copy down. It will sum all values in column 5 that have 1 in column 4.

Comment: You mean I have to put in such a equation my self, manually, every time before the file is opened?

Comment: you could put it in a workbook_open macro, as `sheet1.range("F2:F" & sheet1.cells(rows.count,5).end(xlup).row").formular1c1="=if(RC4=0,"""",sumif(C4,1,C5))"